# Hierarchical tree with nodes

Tags: odoo

I'm writing a module to manage some sort of branches.
Every branch can contain sub-branches.
There is a field (type) which determines the type of the branch (sub or main).

```
 _columns = {
        'name'                  :   fields.char('Name',size=120,required=True),
        'no'                    :   fields.char('Number'),
        'type'                  :   fields.selection([('s','Sub'), ('m','Main Branch ')],'Type',help="Branch type: Main or Sub branch."),
```

I need to show this hierarchy in a view in OpenERP.
I can use the normal tree view like this:

```
<!-- Tree view of branches -->
    <record id="view_branch_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">branchs.branch.tree</field>
        <field name="model">branchs.branch</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="station" >
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="no"/>
                            <field name="type"/>
```

But I don't know how to show them in a hierarchical tree, with main branches as nodes like an account chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do the following:

**1- In the .py file** add a column of type (one2many) that will have the ids of the children and another one that refers to the parent  :

```
'parent_id'    :   fields.many2one('branches.branch','Parent Branches'),
'child_ids'    :   fields.one2many('branches.branch', 'parent_id', 'Children'),
```

**2- In the xml file:**
 add this this field:
                      child_ids

And in the  section change the viewtype to tree:

```
                 <field name="view_type">tree</field>
```

Finally, add this filter in order to show only the parents in the nodes:

```
                 <field name="domain">[('parent_id','=',False)]</field>
```

That's it.

Comment: Interesting... and will this work without mentioning parent_id and child_ids in the view?